# Error detecting database type: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: no pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, configuration, configuration-files, context.xml

I am using pgAdmin3 and used the pkg to install postgreSQL and pg.
I am trying to connect to postgreSQL through tomcat. When I do ./startup.sh from my tomcat /bin directory the log file shows this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaModelDAO' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-coreDataServices.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.cayenne.CayenneRuntimeException: [v.3.0.1.LB Nov 16 2011 05:24:11] Error detecting database type: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.0.0.197", user "abc_writer", database "abc", SSL off)

Here is what I have in my context.xml:

```
  <Context>
    <Resource username="abc_writer" password="levelsbeyond"  
              url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/abc"
             type="javax.sql.DataSource" name="jdbc/abc-workflow" 
             maxWait="10000" maxIdle="20" maxActive="50"
             driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" auth="Container" /> 
 </Context>
```

And here is what my pg_hba.config looks like:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                md5
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
host     abc     abc_writer        10.0.0.197      md5
```

When I open up postmaster from postgresql/bin it reads this:

```
 localhost:~ bryanraymond$ /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/postgres ; exit;
 postgres cannot access the server configuration file    
 "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/postgresql.conf": Permission denied
 logout
```

Would the reason that it says I have no entry in pg_hba.conf be because i dont have permission if so how do I get permission? If that is not the problem do I have something setup wrong?

--- Thanks, Bryan

Comment: What happens when you run `psql -h localhost -U abc_writer -d abc`?

Comment: I get this: localhost:~ bryanraymond$ psql -h localhost -U abc_writer -d abc
psql (9.1.9, server 9.3.0)
WARNING: psql version 9.1, server version 9.3.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

abc=#

Answer (score 2):

You have an erroneous line in your pg_hba.conf. It should read

`host     abc     abc_writer        10.0.0.197/32      md5`

Note the "/32". After making that change you will need to reload your Postgresql config (eg. "pg_ctl reload"). I'm not sure what the "permission denied" bit is about though.

Comment: After changing the pg_hba.conf file I tried pg_ctl restart and I this error.  localhost:~ bryanraymond$ pg_ctl restart
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/postmaster.pid": Permission denied.    I get this error when I do it this way:    localhost:~ bryanraymond$ sudo pg_ctl restart
Password:
pg_ctl: cannot be run as root                                         And when I try to run is at the postgres user I get this             localhost:~ bryanraymond$ su postgres pg_ctl restart
Password:
/usr/local/bin/pg_ctl: /usr/local/bin/pg_ctl: cannot execute binary file

Comment: The postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files should be owned by the postgres user (or whatever OS user owns the postgres $PGDATA data files).